# Pulsar dos veces el botón atras para salir de la App en Android

Tags: java, android

Últimamente las aplicaciones que salen, llevan incorporado lo de presionar dos veces el botón atrás `físico como virtual` para salir de la app, mostrando un mensaje `Presione una ves más para salir.

Tengo implementado lo siguiente:

En `MainActivity` principal declaro la variable `canExitApp` global para establecer si se ha pulsado alguna vez.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...    
private boolean canExitApp = false;
...
```

Y en el método `onBackPressed` compruebo la variable de estado si está a `true` sale de la app si está en `false` muestra el mensaje con un `toast`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    if (!canExitApp) {
        canExitApp = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.app_back_pressed_exit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                canExitApp = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Seria dejar X segundos al usuario para que vuelva a presionar para salir.

Ahora mismo solo funciona en activitys.

¿Cómo puedo añadir soporte para 'fragments', que si no queda ninguno en la pila, detecte si se quiere salir del todo?

Si uso por ejemplo un menú lateral que carga fragments, navego entre ellos, teniendo en cuenta que si hay alguno en pila, lo vaya mostrando, hasta llegar a 0, quiero que funcione la doble pulsación para salir.

Comment: No termino de ver qué es lo que quieres preguntar, ¿podrías aclararlo?

Comment: @Pablo ahora mismo solo funciona en activitys, pero si usas por ejemplo un menú lateral que carga fragments, navegas entre ellos, teniendo en cuenta que si hay alguno en pila, lo vayas mostrando, hasta llegar a 0 y después que actue la doble pulsación para salir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo prefiero no usar hilos para cambiar una variable, sino usar comparaciones de tiempo en base a `System.currentTimeMillis()`. El siguiente código te da 2 segundos para volver a presionar BACK

```
    private static final int INTERVALO = 2000; //2 segundos para salir
    private long tiempoPrimerClick;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (tiempoPrimerClick + INTERVALO > System.currentTimeMillis()){ 
            super.onBackPressed(); 
            return;
        }else { 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Vuelve a presionar para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }        
        tiempoPrimerClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

Comment: Creo que es mejor opción tú método, creo que está mejor optimizado para tal propósito.

Comment: Si te ha sido de ayuda, te pido marcarla como correcta :)

Answer (score 3):

Por si alguien tiene este problema en android pero con Fragments
Solo hay que corroborar que la pila esté vacía para proceder a hacer la comprobación del doble back

```
private static long presionado;
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        //Si tiene fragments simplemente ejecuta la pulsación Back normal
        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0)
            super.onBackPressed();
        else {
            if (presionado + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis())
                super.onBackPressed();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Vuelve a presionar para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            presionado = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar una librería para `Presione de nuevo para cerrar`:
 [librería Shutdown](https://github.com/emmanuelkehinde/Shutdown). Su uso es tan simple que solo se debe añadir en el evento `onBackPressed`:

```
Shutdown.now(this);
```

Mostrará el mensaje  `Press back again to close` y el usuario tiene 3 segundos, que si vuelve a pulsar el botón atrás, se cerrará la app.

Se puede personalizar el texto con:

```
Shutdown.now(this,"Pulse otra vez para cerrar");
```

---

Basándome en la librería Shutdown he creado el siguiente clase

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExitApp {

    private static long lastClickTime;

    public static void now(Activity ctx, @StringRes int message) {
        now(ctx, ctx.getString(message), 2500);
    }

    public static void now(Activity ctx, @StringRes int message, long time) {
        now(ctx, ctx.getString(message), time);
    }

    public static void now(Activity ctx, String message, long time) {
        if (ctx != null && !message.isEmpty() && time != 0) {
            if (lastClickTime + time > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                ctx.finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                lastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Su uso**

```
ExitApp.now(this, R.string.double_back_pressed);
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar esto:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
}

this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Pulsa dos veces para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
    }
}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: deberías de incluir una explicación de porque tú código resuelve la pregunta formulada, para que no sea considerada de baja calidad.