# Como hacer para bloquear al usario el botón "atrás" en mi app

Tags: java, android

Resulta que tengo una app que tiene un botón  de "REINICIAR" para que el usuario vuelva a la pantalla inicial. Peeeero, si no lo hace y simplemente tira para atrás con el botón que tenemos todos la aplicación ya no es lo mismo... No es el objetivo. No lo consigo encontrar.. Me he vuelto loco probando onStop(); introduciéndolo en lo que yo creía el botón de atrás pero sin resultado, estoy muy perdido..

Comment: A que te refieres con el botón que tenemos todos? el back de la aplicación (toolbar) o el de el dispositivo?

Comment: Puede tambien que te interese http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4331/presionar-dos-veces-para-salir-de-la-app-en-android

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar también onBackPressed() para decidir que debe de hacer la app cuando se pulsa el botón "atrás"

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed (){        
    if (condicion) {
        dimeAlgoBonito();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Es algo muy sencillo, debes crear un método (@override), te paso el código:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
```

Solo debes hacer eso, y dentro de el evento no pones nada para que no genere ninguna acción en el momento que presionan el botón físico de atrás.

Comment: Exactamente! Y ya está! Muchísimas gracias, sabía que había una función definida solo para eso pero no sabía cual era, por cierto, tengo mismo problema pero con el botón "Home" porque la música suena y si pulsas "Home" te vas del juego pero la música... sigue sonando. Lo de mp.stop(); dentro de la función está claro pero no sé el nombre, es algo del estilo onHomePressed(); onHomeButton(); ? jaja un saludo y gracias.

Comment: EDITADO: bueno mejor el home button no, ya que no tiene sentido.. pero si como se llama su funcion para poder decir que si se pulsa, mi programa se pare y no siga ejecutando el código...

Comment: Pues he puesto funcion onStop(); super.onStop; mp.stop(); Que SÍ que funciona pero si vuelvo a entrar dentro de la app no suena la música pues está guardado el stop de antes. He puesto un onStart(); pero sin éxito... :( sabes algo? :(

Answer (score 0):

Si es el botón del dispositivo lo puede controlar por medio del siguiente método

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            //Acción
        }
}
```